# Connecting to Mongodb from Django application hosted on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, pymongo

I am trying to connect my djnago application hosted on heroku to mongodb atlas.
I have also changed the DATABASE_URL on heroku settings as:

```
mongodb+srv://<name>:<password>@cluster0.wtnph.mongodb.net/test
```

I am using python 3.9 and django 3.0.5
But when deploying to heroku, I am getting the error.

```
> -----> Python app detected
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
           settings.INSTALLED_APPS
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
           self._setup(name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
           self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
           mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/tmp/build_91bba5c0/kibo_skill_matrix_api/settings.py", line 176, in <module>
           django_heroku.settings(locals())
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_heroku/core.py", line 69, in settings
           config['DATABASES']['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=MAX_CONN_AGE, ssl_require=True)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dj_database_url.py", line 55, in config
           config = parse(s, engine, conn_max_age, ssl_require)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dj_database_url.py", line 103, in parse
           engine = SCHEMES[url.scheme] if engine is None else engine
       KeyError: 'mongodb+srv'
       If you suspect this is an IPython 7.16.1 bug, please report it at:
           https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
       or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org
```

I even tried removing the DATABASE dict from Settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by changing this line in settings.py

From:

```
# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals()),
```

To:

```
# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals(), databases=False),
```